# Jquery .each() and Flickr Json

Tags: jquery, json, flickr

I am looping over the JSON returned from Flickr. I am expecting the following would alert `0,1,2,3...` etc for the index, but instead it is alerting `id,server,farm,etc`

```
$.each(data.photo, function(index,item){
             alert(index);

 });
```

***EDIT***
BTW I am using the `method=flickr.photos.getInfo`

```
var Info = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getInfo";
                Info += "&api_key=" + "myapikey";
            Info+= "&photo_id="+item.id;
            Info += "&format=json";
            Info+= "&jsoncallback=?";

$.getJSON(Info,loaded);

function loaded(){
$.each(data.photo, function(index,item){
      //Trying to get number of JSON Object (I am getting the info for 52 photos)....
      //I want to alert 0 through 52 here and do some further processing

});

}
```

***EDIT***
As pointed out by Engineer I should not be looping over this and instead should just
be using `data.photo.....`

Comment: so if the key of returned JSON possess id, server etc then you will get that, do you want an indexing to each key : property pair?

Comment: Hi yes I need an indexing to each key: property pair. I need to know which one it is 1st, 10th etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.photo` is hashmap, that's why you are getting `(key,value)` pairs in `'each' callback`.

According to [API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getInfo.html) `'method=flickr.photos.getInfo'` returns information of one single photo.This means, `data.photo` is bunch of properties ((key,value) pairs), and there is no meaning to enumerate those.

Comment: Thanks.I need to have an index to each set of JSON returned. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Note that the order of keys in a javascript object may vary...

Comment: @james What do you mean by `'set of JSON'` ?

Comment: Sorry I mean by each object/photo

Comment: @james Can you post some parts of JSON ? And show what output are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @james I have looked at Flickr's API documentation. According to it, you are loading an info just for one photo (by photo_id). And JSON is bunch of properties of just one photo. What is the meaning of enumerating those properties? Or I have misunderstood?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I have figured out my mistake. I am updating my code with correct answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`flickr.photos.getInfo` returns a single photo in object form ({}).

```
{
  photo: { 
   owner: 1,
   title: 'photo title',
   // etc.
  }
}
```

You would only expect to receive numeric keys if (a) they've been assigned to the object (very unusual) or (b) the API method you're using returns an *array* of objects.

```
photos: [{
   owner: 1,
   title: 'photo 1'
}, {
   owner: 1,
   title: 'photo 2'
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want indexing instead of id, server, firm then you can try this

```
var count = 0;
$.each(data.photo, function(index,item){
      alert(index + ' is at ' + count);
      count++;
 });
```